# data from callback to outside (node.js, redis)

Tags: node.js, redis

I have :

```
var g1 = 0,
client.get('r:'+data[i]+':g1:'+(timestamp), function(err, clicks){
    g1 = clicks;
});

console.log(g1);
```

but not working, how i can get data outside redis callback function ?

Comment: If `client.get()` is asynchronous, it's not going to work. Being asynchronous means that it doesn't wait for the task to complete, so `console.log(g1)` will execute before `g1 = clicks`. You'll have to work with `g1` or `clicks` inside the callback.

Comment: You might also have a look at "[How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)." It focuses on Ajax and jQuery, but the general issue is the same. And, for some of the library-specific solutions, Node.js has its own equivalents -- such as [Q](https://npmjs.org/package/q) for "Deferreds/Promises."

Comment: for my purpose i found another way. I used redis and get i change to mget. Now no need send data outside.